# How to get the HD Texture pack?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I read somewhere that Skyrim just received a new patch that added the possibility to get an HD Texture Pack.

I launched Steam but no patches incoming. I did the usual check of game cache but it seems all correct. I also searched for this pack in Steam Workshop but nothing,

What am I missing?

Comment: can you get to this link? http://store.steampowered.com/app/202485

Comment: Just for what its worth. My computer significantly exceeds the recommended hardware for the HD texture pack, but it adds considerably to the load times of the game and does -not- Greatly increase the graphics in the game while playing the game. There is a noticable crispness when standing and looking at a scene, but its not worth the trade off if your intent is not to take screen shots and instead actually play the game.

Comment: @James that's because your bottle neck is probably your hard drive, the best gpu/cpu in the world can't speed up loading of a lot of large high res textures.  If you get a SSD/hybrid drive then it'll probably improve a lot.

Comment: @yx I have a striped raid array of two 300gb velociraptors.. While I admit that SSD can be faster (right now just the heating concerns on most on board chipsets for running SSDs in RAID makes me not want to go to them, I just use em in my laptops), my system is fairly responsive even from a drive load perspective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install it as you would any other game/DLC.

You can go directly to [its page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/202485/) using any browser and click `Install Game` which should open up Steam and start downloading it.

[image: Steam DLC download]

After you do that, you can see it linked to the game in Steam

[image: DLC]

Alternatively, you can click `view available downloadable content for this game` from that last screen from inside Steam, which will take you to a page where you can also start the download, and looks like this:

[image: All DLC for game]

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was so excited to get it that I forgot the obvious.

Answer (score 4):

On the Steam page for Skyrim, click on DLC, that should take you to the install page.

Edit: The DLC link is on the right-hand sidebar, under "Links". Or just click on the link Marcelo and yx posted :P

Comment: http://store.steampowered.com/app/202485/